# How to get Google Cloud Translation used Chars via API?G

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, translation, quota

how do i get information from this page '**https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas**' programmatically, i couldn't find any API service to do this, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible to achieve, however, there's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80238692) to consider having this functionality.